# Servlet: request.getParameter() seems to extend itself, not overwrite

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

So, i have this form:

```
<input type="radio" name="item" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="item" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="item" value="3">
```

When an item is chosen and button submitted (form method: post), the doPost() will run and print out the request.getParameter("item");  . First time, it works good, if I chose item1, it will print out "1 ". So now i select item3 and hit submit. I expect that "3 " will be printed out, but instead "1 3" is printed out. And then if i choose item2 and submit, it prints out "1 3 2 ".

To me it seems that the post variable isn't overrided, but extends itself?

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {      
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    html += request.getParameter("vare");

    out.println("post" + html);
}
```

Comment: Maybe because of the `+=` operator.

Answer (score 0):

What are you suppose to do with the below line:

```js
html += request.getParameter("vare");
```

where have you declared the "html" variable(gloabally?) ?
in above line you are appending the each post value to 'html' variable. not assigning the current posted value. so yes, it is extending (appending)..

Answer (score 0):

Your `html` variable is a class member and so it is being re-used from request to request. This means that your servlet is not thread-safe. Nice job.

You want to put the declaration of your variable inside the `doPost` method and your problems will be solved:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  throws ServletException, IOException
{
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

  String html = request.getParameter("vare");

  out.println("post" + html);
}
```